# How to make a simple smartphone controlled power switch?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, arduino, usb

I want to be able to push a button in an app running on my Android phone and have a power switch on a real circuit literally attached to the phone be turned on/off. I'm having trouble thinking of a good way to do it. So far I've thought of:

1) Using an Arduino
The biggest problem with this is that the Arduino needs to be loaded with a sketch in order to work, and I can't use a PC to do the job. I've seen Arduino Commander but it's freemium and not open source, and I need to write my own custom app. It seems that I would have to find a way to load sketches and also write my own driver. This is not a pleasing course of action.

2) Playing an audio tone from the earphone jack
The idea is to play a tone that can then be converted into a small DC voltage. That DC voltage will then be used as the gate voltage to a MOSFET, which will act as the switch. The problem with this is that undesired audio can unexpectedly turn on the switch. For my application, even a small chance of this is unacceptable. Even filtering doesn't eliminate interference completely. Can I some how exclude all other sources of sound and only have an audio tone as output? If not over the headphone jack itself, over Bluetooth?

If anyone has any helpful thoughts, please share them.

Comment: i dont know to much about this but you could use arduino with the ethernet adapter then hook up the android with a socket connection or something like that http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield

Comment: If you can't use a pc to pre-program a microcontroller, how can you use one to develop an Android app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the second method with a specific audio to be played with some intervals which only triggers the switch instead of any audio being able to change the switch state, It does contain a little latency to be triggered but if its okay then it may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify some miss information, the Arduino IDE is available at no charge for use on Windows, Mac OS, Linux, Raspberry pi and maybe others. With the IDE you can write, download your code to the Arduino and debut it.